# org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: entry

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, cypher, bouncycastle

I have a sample code in which I am just decrypting a data with public key and I am getting "org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: entry"  ERROR

It is throwing exception when i am trying to create an instance of Cipher

```
   private static boolean checkHashPadding(PublicKey key, byte[] 
signature) {

    if(key.getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase("RSA")) {
        try {
            // Unencrypt the data to get the hash (as in PKCS#1 format)
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding", new 
    BouncyCastleFipsProvider()); // -- IT is Failing here
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] hashDER = c.doFinal(signature);
            System.out.println(hashDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

mainFunction:

public static void main(String s[]){

```
byte[] signature = {
            41, 9, 86, 109, -67, 82, -61, -60, -1, -46, 26, 65, 20, -112, 23, -16, -25, 115, 21, 39, -49,
            11, -98, 44, 96, -51, 24, -97, -38, -72, 27, -119, 16, -43, 38, -49, -116, 3, 62, 12, -7, 102, 67, -37,
            -128, -10, 3, 122, -22, -2, -58, 97, 104, 74, 76, -45, 19, 50, 34, 33, -74, 54, 44, -60, 23, -109, -6,
            -3, -31, -98, -58, 12, -94, -72, -15, -72, 22, 88, -54, 5, 122, -29, -27, -74, 47, -127, 26, 120, 64,
            59, 53, -82, -97, -80, -66, 48, -16, 26, 17, 60, 104, 78, -91, 2, 78, 33, -18, -60, 30, -118, -51, 29,
            0, -48, 87, -112, 23, 70, 127, -80, 116, -93, -1, 51, -56, -110, 86, -68
            };

    byte[] signatureBytes = {48, -126, 4, 6, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 7, 2, -96, -126, 3, -9, 48, -126, 3, -13, 2, 1, 1, 49, 15, 48, 13, 6, 9, 96,
            -122, 72, 1, 101, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 0, 48, 11, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 7, 1, -96, -126, 2, -116, 48, -126, 2, -120, 48, -126, 1, -15, 2,
            4, 68, 42, 24, 78, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 4, 5, 0, 48, -127, -118, 49, 11, 48, 9, 6, 3, 85, 4, 6, 19, 2, 85, 83, 49, 11, 
            48, 9, 6, 3, 85, 4, 8, 19, 2, 67, 65, 49, 17, 48, 15, 6, 3, 85, 4, 7, 19, 8, 83, 97, 110, 32, 74, 111, 115, 101, 49, 28, 48, 26, 6, 3, 85, 4, 10,
            19, 19, 65, 100, 111, 98, 101, 32, 83, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 115, 44, 32, 73, 110, 99, 46, 49, 17, 48, 15, 6, 3, 85, 4, 11, 19, 8, 67, 111, 114,
            101, 74, 97, 118, 97, 49, 42, 48, 40, 6, 3, 85, 4, 3, 19, 33, 74, 111, 101, 32, 67, 111, 111, 108, 32, 40, 83, 101, 108, 102, 83, 105, 103, 110, 101,
            100, 45, 49, 48, 50, 52, 66, 105, 116, 45, 82, 83, 65, 41, 48, 30, 23, 13, 48, 54, 48, 51, 50, 57, 48, 53, 49, 55, 48, 50, 90, 23, 13, 49, 54, 48,
            51, 50, 54, 48, 53, 49, 55, 48, 50, 90, 48, -127, -118, 49, 11, 48, 9, 6, 3, 85, 4, 6, 19, 2, 85, 83, 49, 11, 48, 9, 6, 3, 85, 4, 8, 19, 2, 67, 65,
            49, 17, 48, 15, 6, 3, 85, 4, 7, 19, 8, 83, 97, 110, 32, 74, 111, 115, 101, 49, 28, 48, 26, 6, 3, 85, 4, 10, 19, 19, 65, 100, 111, 98, 101, 32, 83,
            121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 115, 44, 32, 73, 110, 99, 46, 49, 17, 48, 15, 6, 3, 85, 4, 11, 19, 8, 67, 111, 114, 101, 74, 97, 118, 97, 49, 42, 48, 40, 
            6, 3, 85, 4, 3, 19, 33, 74, 111, 101, 32, 67, 111, 111, 108, 32, 40, 83, 101, 108, 102, 83, 105, 103, 110, 101, 100, 45, 49, 48, 50, 52, 66, 105,
            116, 45, 82, 83, 65, 41, 48, -127, -97, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, -127, -115, 0, 48, -127, -119, 2, -127, -127, 0,
            -48, -82, 98, -106, -36, -91, -33, -39, 37, 83, -27, 66, -78, -31, -67, 18, 60, -108, -121, -41, 10, -70, 104, -98, -54, -93, 110, 46, 64, -10, -86,
            28, -29, 127, 4, -66, -24, 54, 38, 119, -93, 127, 107, 80, 6, 23, 115, 76, 0, 103, -127, 39, 98, -69, -36, -47, -89, -97, 73, -69, -83, 96, 68, 20, 67, 64, -39, -57, -124, 92, -77, 33, 47, 46, -4, -36, 123, 92, -117, 57, -38, -108, -16, -112, -19, 106, 87, -90, -49, -60, 18, -61, 80, 66, 78, 102, -121, -37, 31, 42, -51, 113, 24, 123, 50, 8, 41, 101, -53, 48, 89, 28, 61, 64, 104, -73, 110, -10, 125, 6, 94, -126, 101, -50, -73, 66, -119, 13, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 4, 5, 0, 3, -127, -127, 0, 19, 25, -55, -23, 18, -13, -64, -9, -75, 74, -106, 78, -55, 23, -29, 18, -3, -37, 30, 77, -4, -13, -120, -1, -103, 34, -12, 65, 69, 7, 94, -124, 104, 90, -4, -86, -27, 0, 16, 97, 104, 116, 118, 117, -99, 78, 75, 23, 58, -121, 66, -72, -6, -16, -21, -8, 2, -44, 22, -9, -54, 100, 104, 14, 125, 96, 37, 98, 82, -123, 109, 47, -14, -35, 114, 27, -65, 11, 28, -77, -90, 40, -112, -13, 99, 44, 125, 99, -23, -17, -77, 58, 20, 21, -98, -78, 39, -120, -103, 119, -24, 8, 123, 69, 26, -107, 65, 98, 100, 0, 20, 79, -119, 93, 29, 68, 95, 102, 19, 112, -89, 122, -47, 95, -35, -61, 35, -119, 49, -126, 1, 62, 48, -126, 1, 58, 2, 1, 1, 48, -127, -109, 48, -127, -118, 49, 11, 48, 9, 6, 3, 85, 4, 6, 19, 2, 85, 83, 49, 11, 48, 9, 6, 3, 85, 4, 8, 19, 2, 67, 65, 49, 17, 48, 15, 6, 3, 85, 4, 7, 19, 8, 83, 97, 110, 32, 74, 111, 115, 101, 49, 28, 48, 26, 6, 3, 85, 4, 10, 19, 19, 65, 100, 111, 98, 101, 32, 83, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 115, 44, 32, 73, 110, 99, 46, 49, 17, 48, 15, 6, 3, 85, 4, 11, 19, 8, 67, 111, 114, 101, 74, 97, 118, 97, 49, 42, 48, 40, 6, 3, 85, 4, 3, 19, 33, 74, 111, 101, 32, 67, 111, 111, 108, 32, 40, 83, 101, 108, 102, 83, 105, 103, 110, 101, 100, 45, 49, 48, 50, 52, 66, 105, 116, 45, 82, 83, 65, 41, 2, 4, 68, 42, 24, 78, 48, 13, 6, 9, 96, -122, 72, 1, 101, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 0, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 4, -127, -128, 41, 9, 86, 109, -67, 82, -61, -60, -1, -46, 26, 65, 20, -112, 23, -16, -25, 115, 21, 39, -49, 11, -98, 5, 96, -51, 24, -97, -38, -72, 27, -119, 16, -43, 38, -49, -116, 3, 62, 12, -7, 102, 67, -37, -128, -10, 3, 122, -22, -2, -58, 97, 104, 74, 76, -45, 19, 50, 34, 33, -74, 54, 44, -60, 23, -109, -6, -3, -31, -98, -58, 12, -94, -72, -15, -72, 22, 88, -54, 5, 122, -29, -27, -74, 47, -127, 26, 120, 64, 59, 53, -82, -97, -80, -66, 48, -16, 26, 17, 60, 104, 78, -91, 2, 78, 33, -18, -60, 30, -118, -51, 29, 0, -48, 87, -112, 23, 70, 127, -80, 116, -93, -1, 51, -56, -110, 86, -68};

    InputStream signatureStream = null;
        signatureStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(signatureBytes, 0,signatureBytes.length);
        CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(signatureStream);
        JcaCertStoreBuilder storeBuilder = new JcaCertStoreBuilder();
        storeBuilder.addCertificates(signedData.getCertificates());
        storeBuilder.addCRLs(signedData.getCRLs());
        CertStore certStore = storeBuilder.build();
        SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos();
        Iterator it = signers.getSigners().iterator();
        SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
        SignerId signer_id = signer.getSID();
        JcaX509CertSelectorConverter conv = new JcaX509CertSelectorConverter(); 
        X509CertificateHolderSelector sel = new X509CertificateHolderSelector(signer_id.getIssuer(),
                signer_id.getSerialNumber()); 
        X509CertSelector signerConstraints = conv.getCertSelector(sel); 

        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certStore.getCertificates(signerConstraints).iterator().next();
        PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();

    checkHashPadding(key, signature);
```

}

Adding stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum 
failed: entry
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.checksumValidate(Unknown 
Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.isReady(Unknown Source)
at 
org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.getDefaultMode(Unknown 
Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.<clinit>(Unknown 
Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init> 
(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>
```

(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider. 
    (Unknown Source)
    at

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: entry
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:342)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:412)
... 9 more
```

Comment: If you need FIPS, make sure you are using the bc-fips jar _exactly_ as downloaded from BC with no changes of any kind; if you don't need FIPS (and 99% of users don't) don't use it (in that case you don't really need BC provider in Oracle/Sun/OpenJDK for RSA signature, but you do need BC for CMS so you might as well use it).

Comment: I need FIPS jars and I am using one still, It is showing error.

Comment: The NPE implies you have a truncated jar file, download it again. There are also SHA1 and SHA256 checksums available from the download page, so check the file against those.

Comment: I downloaded the checksums and it is not matching with checksum in the jar's META-INF/HMAC.SHA256 . And the checksum is different even  when I downloaded the jars again.

Comment: Also in documentation it is written that "module checksum fails with a NullPointerException if module jar on boot classpath" -- so what is "module jar on boot classpath"

Comment: The checksum you have to calculate yourself on the downloaded file using e.g. "openssl sha256 file.jar"

Comment: @AmritRaj  You are referring to a defect that was already fixed in BC-FJA 1.0.1, which received certification just last week. Are you using 1.0.1?

Comment: I had this problem because I tried to put this in a fat jar... basically it does not work

Comment: @MiguelCosta you mean that if you include FIPS BC into Fat Jar it won't work? Is there a reason why it does not work?

Comment: @Maksim it says in their document documentation that it does not work. Something to do with the checksum of the package and how it's used for the signing I think

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown:

1. When BC FIPS jar is corrupt as there is a method to calculate the checksum of jar and validate it with `META-INF/HMAC.SHA256`;
2. When it is used with some other jars for example, in my case I had `bc-fips-source.jar`. When I removed it from build path in eclipse my sample code started working.

Comment: In general source .jar's should not be added to the classpath. You can refer to them in your IDE, but they should not ever be in the classpath itself.

Answer (score 0):

For users of eclipse, use the "package required libraries" rather than the default "extract required libraries" option when generating a jar file.
For Intellij users, use the non-default "copy to the output directory".

I prefer eclipse in this regard as it packages the libraries within the target jar archive meaning the result is more portable.